# How to call a jquery function once every 24 hours?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm working on getting a banner on my website to inform visitors about cookies. I want to apply this banner using jquery, and when people click "OK" it should go away. That part I can do, but I want it to reappear if they visit the site again after 24 hours. I guess I can do this with a cookie, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Cookie is your best bet, but won't work if people have them turned off.

Comment: I can't help in the jQuery department, but I'd be careful about showing the banner every 24 hours as you'll annoy a lot of people and potentially drive them away. What's the purpose of showing the banner after they've already accepted the cookie policy?

Comment: I agree with @Tim, that is a UX design flaw.

Comment: Your title is confusing, which is why you are getting irrelevant answers.

Comment: @JeppeWillesenSmith Is this question still open? If not, please close the question (by choosing a best answer) and upvoting any answers that were helpful to you. You can come back later to do that if you don't yet have enough rep. If you wish to fine-tune your question, it is usually best to close the original question and ask a new one (the new question will appear at the top of the list and will have maximum exposure).

Answer (score 1):

JQuery doesn't have a built in cookie handler, but its really not that hard in regular js. As @Tim has mentioned this is bad user-experience design, you shouldn't annoy people with popups like that. Once is enough. But I understand why you might want to make sure it doesn't pop-up everytime. If you want to, you can set the date to a VERY far-future date to help prevent it from showing up again, until the user clears there cookies that is.

Set the cookie like this

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

And retrieve it like this.

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
```

You can use the whole thing like this...

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
```

*Taken directly from here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp*
    }

Comment: while this is a pretty good answer for cookies, please avoid using w3schools for future references.

Comment: Why? It's valid isn't it? I mean I could rewrite it simpler if referencing isn't allowed or something.

Comment: w3 as an organization has denounced it because it proliferates bad information, while also profiting on the ignorance of users through their bull**** certifications. its just good practice to cite a more appropriate and legitimate source. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Ahhh. Understood. I only use it from time to time as a "documentation" source, and to pull quick info like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use localStorage, adding current date on click:

```
var curDate = new Date();

$('#Button').on('click',function(){
    localStorage['banner'] = curDate.getDate();
});
```

Then check if it exists, and compared the dates:

```
if(localStorage['banner'].length > 0){
    var future = new Date();
    future.setDate(localStorage['banner'] + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    if(future > curDate){
        localStorage['banner'].length = 0;
    }
}
```

This will work if they are using the same browser, just like a cookie would. A note that this will only work for IE8 and above, encompassing only 99.2% of users worldwide.

Comment: Local storage is a nice touch, but not completely cross-platform compatible.

Comment: 99.2% is pretty specific. =P

Comment: its a half-joke ... its also based on a few research sites denoting < 1% usage worldwide of IE6 and IE7, as good as those stats sites are at least.

Answer (score 0):

For less code, simpler implementation try this:

[jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Examples:

Create a cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Read a cookie:

```
var cookieval = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Create an expiring cookie (expires after 7 days):

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

[Source](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using by writing a very simple `freshVistor(howFresh)` function which accepts an optional argument to define how fresh you view as "fresh."

```
function freshVisitor(howFresh) {
    var namespace = 'freshVisitorSOCookie';
    if (readCookie(namespace)) {
        return false;
    }
    return makeCookie(namespace, 'yes', {
        expires: howFresh || 1
    });
}
```

Your application can use the `freshVisitor()` function like this:

```
if (freshVisitor()) {
    /* This means the user is new or has not visited within 1 day
     * So show your banner or do something that you want to do */
} else {
    /* The user has visited already within the previous day
     * or has disabled cookies. */
}
```

You can also specify your own definition of "fresh:"

```
if (freshVisitor(2)) ... /* uses a 2-day period to calculate freshness */
```

Please note! For user friendliness, I have made this function *automatically return false* when the user has cookies disabled, in order to prevent the circumstance of someone without cookies being overwhelmed with banner ads. I believe this is the right way to treat people who are visiting my website, but if you wish to reverse this respectful behavior, feel free to adjust the logic within my `freshVisitor()` code.

Of course, you need appropriate cookie functions that can calculate expiration dates using the notation above, so here is the full code:

```
<script>
    function makeCookie(name, value, p) {
        var s, k;

        function reldate(days) {
            var d;
            d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + days * 86400000);
            return d.toGMTString();
        }
        s = escape(name) + '=' + escape(value);
        if (p)
            for (k in p) {

                /* convert a numeric expires value to a relative date */

                if (k == 'expires')
                    p[k] = isNaN(p[k]) ? p[k] : reldate(p[k]);

                /* The secure property is the only special case
here, and it causes two problems. Rather than
being '; protocol=secure' like all other
properties, the secure property is set by
appending '; secure', so we have to use a
ternary statement to format the string.

The second problem is that secure doesn't have
any value associated with it, so whatever value
people use doesn't matter. However, we don't
want to surprise people who set { secure: false }.
For this reason, we actually do have to check
the value of the secure property so that someone
won't end up with a secure cookie when
they didn't want one. */

                if (p[k])
                    s += '; ' + (k != 'secure' ? k + '=' + p[k] : k);
            }
        document.cookie = s;
        return readCookie(name) == value;
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var s = document.cookie,
            i;
        if (s)
            for (i = 0, s = s.split('; '); i < s.length; i++) {
                s[i] = s[i].split('=', 2);
                if (unescape(s[i][0]) == name)
                    return unescape(s[i][1]);
            }
        return null;
    }

    function removeCookie(name) {
        return !makeCookie(name, '', {
            expires: -1
        });
    }

    function freshVisitor(howFresh) {
        var namespace = 'freshVisitorSOCookie';
        if (readCookie(namespace)) {
            return false;
        }
        return makeCookie(namespace, 'yes', {
            expires: howFresh || 1
        });
    }

    document.write('Fresh visitor status: ', freshVisitor());
</script>
```